# Making the switch from freelance — should I put clients on CV?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, freelancing

I'm a graphic designer who has been working freelance more or less my entire career, apart from a couple of jobs where I was working part-time (and neither were particularly well suited to my ambitions so I didn't pick up much valuable experience from them).

Although I've never properly benefited from working within a design agency with a senior designer or creative director to guide me, I have worked with a number of different agencies on a freelance basis. This has occasionally been in-house but most of it has been working on projects remotely for them.

I'm thinking of including some of these clients in my CV along with my previous jobs. I feel some of these clients will be more relevant to my CV than others, but some were for freelance projects that only lasted for about a week or so.

Would it still be a good idea to include some of these despite me having been there for such a short amount of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have worked with a number of different agencies on a freelance
>   basis. This has occasionally been in-house but most of it has been
>   working on projects remotely for them.
>
> I feel some of these clients will be more relevant to my CV than
>   others, but some were for freelance projects that only lasted for
>   about a week or so.
>
> Would it still be a good idea to include some of these despite me
>   having been there for such a short amount of time?

It would be a good idea to name-drop some of the agencies with whom you worked while you were a freelancer. That's particularly true if these agencies are well-know to your potential employers.

Balance that against the "well it was only for 3 days" effect.

If the name is big enough, and if you can honestly describe your work for them as at least somewhat impactful, then include them. On the other hand if you were there for a few days and nobody noticed, omit them.

Remember, that whatever you list on your CV might turn into a target for a reference check. So if you drop their name make sure at least someone at the agency would know you.

Comment: Are prospective employers allowed to target for reference checks in that way, I mean without the candidate first giving permission to contact them ?